# java.lang.IllegalAccessError while ant build in SAP Hybris/Commerce version 2105

Tags: java, ant, sap-commerce-cloud

I am new to Hybris and trying to setup the Hybris latest version, I am trying to build it using ant clean all and getting the below error. I am using SAP Machine JDK 17 and also set it's path in Environment variables. Please help how to solve this!

```
** Java version **
C:\CXCOMM210500P_5-70005661\hybris\bin\platform>java -version
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Djava.vendor="Sun Microsystems Inc."
openjdk version "17.0.1" 2021-10-19 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment SapMachine (build 17.0.1+12-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM SapMachine (build 17.0.1+12-LTS, mixed mode, sharing)

** Error logs **

C:\CXCOMM210500P_5-70005661\hybris\bin\platform\resources\ant\mavenTasks.xml:201: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.oopsconsultancy.xmltask.jdk15.XPathAnalyser15 (in unnamed module @0x2f9f7dcf) cannot access class com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.XPathAPI (in module java.xml) because module java.xml does not export com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal to unnamed module @0x2f9f7dcf
        at com.oopsconsultancy.xmltask.jdk15.XPathAnalyser15.analyse(XPathAnalyser15.java:28)
        at com.oopsconsultancy.xmltask.XmlReplace.apply(XmlReplace.java:72)
        at com.oopsconsultancy.xmltask.XmlReplacement.apply(XmlReplacement.java:61)
        at com.oopsconsultancy.xmltask.ant.XmlTask.processDoc(XmlTask.java:692)
        at com.oopsconsultancy.xmltask.ant.XmlTask.execute(XmlTask.java:661)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:299)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
```

Comment: the issue with the java version only please use answer given by @mkysoft

Comment: FWIW - I'm using `sapmachine:18` via Docker on `2205` (per link from @mkysoft) and still get a similar error message...

Comment: Same, using sapmachine 2205 with recommended jdk17.0 and am getting same error.

Comment: Managed to fix it I think, at least I can progress. Issue was with deperecation, moving from jdk 11 to jdk 17 probably caused some; adding in the option "--add-opens <thing>" into JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS environment variable fixed it, in my case it would be 
"--add-opens java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal=ALL_UNNAMED"

Got it from:
https://blogs.oracle.com/javamagazine/post/its-time-to-move-your-applications-to-java-17-heres-why-and-heres-how

Comment: For 2205 you have to run .setantenv before the build

Answer (score 2):

Unable to add a comment to original question. The solution proposed by [@dmytrolysak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6008020/dmytro-lysak) worked for me. I had to add the option `"--add-opens java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal=ALL-UNNAMED"` in my setantenv.sh for ANT_OPTS.

This is for hybris version 2205 and Java version is sapMachine 17.x.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use SAP Machine 11.0 as JDK for version 2105.
Full system requirements by versions are [here](https://gunce.mkysoft.com/hybris-requirements/).

Answer (score 1):

I came across this error in my Azure pipeline build after upgrading from SAP Commerce 2105 to 2211:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class 
com.oopsconsultancy.xmltask.jdk15.XPathAnalyser15 (in unnamed module 
@0x4b5a078a) cannot access class com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.XPathAPI (in 
module java.xml) 
because module java.xml does not export com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal to 
unnamed module @0x4b5a078a
```

The pipeline build was getting that error when trying to run the following scriptlet from my azure-pipelines.yml file:

```
- task: Ant@1
  inputs:
    buildFile: '$(workspace)/hybris/bin/platform'
    options: 'addoninstall -DaddonStorefront.yacceleratorstorefront=mystorefront -Daddonnames="b2bacceleratoraddon,commerceorgaddon,assistedservicestorefront,smarteditaddon,sapcoreaddon,b2bpunchoutaddon,myraddon,b2boccaddon"'
    javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
    jdkVersionOption: '1.17'
    publishJUnitResults: false
  displayName: ANT - install add-ons
```

In upgrading from 2105 to 2211, we upgraded java from 11 to 17. The first problem that I had to get past was using the correct the java version. I had to include the following scriptlet towards the beginning my azure-pipelines.yml file to make sure I was using java 17:

```
- task: JavaToolInstaller@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '17'
    jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
    jdkSourceOption: 'PreInstalled'
  displayName: 'Installing Java 17'
```

Before I did this, I found that azure pipelines was using the operating system installed version of java, which was version 11. After I added the above scriptlet, that took care of that problem, but I was still getting the IllegalAccessError.

I played around with the ANT_OPTS variable with the "--add-opens java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal=ALL-UNNAMED" option, but that didn't fix anything for me. While working with the environment variables, I discovered that the version of ant being used was the operating system installed version and not the version included with SAP Commerce. I had been running the setantenv.sh command in a
separate scriptlet, thinking that this would properly set the ANT_HOME variable to point to the correct location, and I guess this was being lost once that scriptlet finished and the next one was being run.

What fixed the problem for me was not using the 'ANT - install add-ons' scriptlet mentioned above in lieu of replacing it with a 'script' type scriptlet where I run the baseline configuration, addoninstall, and clean all commands in the same scriptlet:

```
- script: |
    cd $(workspace)/hybris/bin/platform
    . ./setantenv.sh

    echo "JAVA_HOME = $JAVA_HOME"
    echo "ANT_HOME = $ANT_HOME"
    echo "ANT_OPTS = $ANT_OPTS"

    $(ANT_HOME)/bin/ant clean all -Dinput.template=develop

    /usr/bin/cp -r $(workspace)/hybris/bin/custom/core-customize/config/. $(workspace)/hybris/config
    rc=$?
    if [ x"$rc" != x"0" ]; then 
        exit -1
    fi

    $(ANT_HOME)/bin/ant addoninstall -DaddonStorefront.yacceleratorstorefront=graybarstorefront -Daddonnames="b2bacceleratoraddon,commerceorgaddon,assistedservicestorefront,smarteditaddon,sapcoreaddon,b2bpunchoutaddon,graybaraddon,b2boccaddon"
    rc=$?
    if [ x"$rc" != x"0" ]; then 
        exit -1
    fi

    $(ANT_HOME)/bin/ant clean all
    rc=$?
    if [ x"$rc" != x"0" ]; then 
        exit -1
    fi

  displayName: Running the ANT commands
```

Now the azure pipeline build is working correctly for me.

Answer (score 0):

SAP Machine JDK 17 is too **high** for SAP commerce cloud 2105. 
Please use SAP Machine JDK 11 instead.
[Here](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_COMMERCE/a74589c3a81a4a95bf51d87258c0ab15/8c71300f866910149b40c88dfc0de431.html) is SAP official guide for SAP commerce cloud installation.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For Docker users make sure to use the appropriate [sapmachine image](https://hub.docker.com/_/sapmachine) based on your version of SAP Commerce, as mentioned by @mkysoft above.

Also note for newer versions (2205) you do need version 17.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the correct Java version, better use the **SAPMachine** instead of Java for no-nonsense compatibility issues: https://github.com/SAP/SapMachine

**2105 requires Version 11, and 2205 needs 17**

Also, add these exports to your **setantenv**:

```
export ANT_OPTS="-Xmx2g -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 \
--add-exports java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal=ALL-UNNAMED \
--add-exports java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.objects=ALL-UNNAMED"
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use any JDK (from Oracle or SAP). **This seems that the ANT was not set properly**.
In the platform folder, just executed:

```
\hybris\bin\platform> setantenv.bat
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue while generating a new extension.

My Environment Details:
SAP Commerce Version: **2205.9** , SapMachine: Java **17**.0.9

I investigated my ANT_OPTS in the following path.

```
...\hybris\bin\platform\setantenv.sh
```

It already has this code below:

```
export ANT_OPTS="-Xmx2g -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 \
--add-exports java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal=ALL-UNNAMED \
--add-exports java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.objects=ALL-UNNAMED"
```

I solved it by running **setantenv.bat** at the beginning on **Command Prompt**. My build was failing since I was using Powershell and “ANT_HOME” was defined globally from Environment Variables in Windows.